# 2 questions: 1) long 2 wide data in R, 2) followup re: rattle

Tags: r, statistics

1) long to wide question:

I have a dataset with 3 columns:
person, event, frequency.
If the frequency is zero, the row is not in the table. Is there a simple way using basic R functions or libraries to convert this table to wide format, with one row per person and one column per event with the frequency as the value in table.

2) rattle question:

On a related note, is this even necessary for Rattle to understand as an input?

I am trying to import some data into R to explore some of Rattle's machine learning algorithms.

Thanks!
Patrick McCann

Comment: You are probably referring to the 'Rattle' package.

Comment: thanks dirk, i edited to reflect that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part of your question, you can either use the `reshape()` function that's in base R or use the `reshape` package (with the `cast()` function).

Here's an example of using the `reshape()` function (from the help file):

```
wide <- reshape(Indometh, v.names="conc", idvar="Subject",
              timevar="time", direction="wide")
```

Here's a simple example of using `melt` and `cast` (from the reshape help):

```
library(reshape)
names(airquality) <- tolower(names(airquality))
aqm <- melt(airquality, id=c("month", "day"), na.rm=TRUE)    
cast(aqm, month ~ variable, mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Re: the first part, you can filter out the rows with `Frequency == 0` by

```
filteredRows <- data$Frequency != 0
## restrict ourselves to looking at the data where Frequency != 0.
data[filteredRows,]
```